# Web Scenario with Authentication that requires a ViewState

Tags: zabbix

I am new to Zabbix. 
Trying to create Web Scenario that verifies web login with ViewState.

so trying to query VIEWSTATE from a login page with regex (so I can pass it when I am logging in) like this:

```
regex:id="__VIEWSTATE\" value="(.*)
```

[image]

This is what I am trying to query:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="5000_character_long_hash">
```

Questions:
Is this the correct way of doing authentications that require VIEWSTATE hash to be passed with the login? or is there some other method?
Is my regex correct? 
How can I easily verify if Zabbix took my regex correctly?
How can I see the output of {VIEWSTATE} variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing variables from a step to another, in Web Scenario is currently not possible.

There is also no way of knowing if your regexp is correct, because Web Scenario doesn't output anything like that: its only output are speed, error condition, and if a hardcoded string was found.

You also can not use dependent items, or HTTP Client item. So, you need to create an [external check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external).

Comment: thanks.  basically, I will just create a script that will do the same and by-pass zabbix all together.

Comment: yes, you bypass the agent buildt-in keys, adding a custom one. The result of the script will be an item, and that item can have triggers, etc etc.